# HTML anchors not working on server

Tags: html, wordpress, server

My links to anchors aren´t working and I don´t know why. I guess it is something about the server where I have my site uploaded.

I tested my page on a free server and localhost and there are no troubles, it only happens on the server.  Any idea why this might be happening?

The sidebar at the right contains the links that get you to spots on the same page, just works once, but when the page finish loading, doesn't work anymore

This is the page:
http://www.fumigacionesmillenium.com.ve/

Comment: You're getting a LOT of javascript errors after running the scroll animation. It looks like you're also loading multiple versions of jQuery, so you may want to address that issue first and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am inspecting the source and JS console, there seems to be lots of JS errors after I click the link on the right.  Attaching a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think meta tag is not closing proper.Please check below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I installed a plugin called Slideshow, i´m using Wordpress, the reason of the error:

> TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

It was a conflict between the Jquery that loads the plugin and the Jquery that loads from functions.php, solved it this way:

code before:

```
if( !is_admin()){

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'material-jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', array(), '1.0', false );


}
```

code after:

```
if( !is_admin()){

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"), false, '2.1.3');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');


}
```

Now i can use the plugin without problems, and my anchors are working perfectly.